# Noise from shocks/rack ends in Honda Fit

Tags: honda, steering, shock-absorber, fit, cv-joint

In my Honda Fit GP5 I'm getting a metal scrape *("chiri chiri")* noise when my left front wheel hit a rough road with shocks. I'm not getting any noise or anything wired voice when I'm turning the steering wheel. I worried whether I'm having any trouble with my rack ends since I hit a speed bumper on the road around 80Kmh few weeks back. Does any one have any opinion about this problem and what's the best thing to do? (eg. whether do a wheel alignment first) Thank you very much.

[image: left shock]

Comment: What is a "bumbler"?

Comment: Typing mistake. should be 'bumper'. Corrected the original question.

Comment: Get your shocks checked. A friend was using mine and didn’t get them checked. Long story short bad shocks = new links + New steering rack + new shocks
:(